How to setup LAN to WAN connection between two routers
I have two routers which I want to establish a LAN to WAN connection. 
my primary router (router: TP LINK WR840N) LAN settings 
IP: 192.168.0.1 
DHCP: enabled 
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Now for the first time when I connected the LAN to the secondary router's (router: TENDA N300) WAN (which was more than a year ago), it showed the connection status to dynamic, and it worked on its own. Now after a year, the connection of secondary router was not working properly. After hard reset, it is now showing static IP. 
What I have done 
I reset the secondary router again, and it is still showing that it has detected static IP.
when I put the IP: 192.168.0.105 and gateway as 192.168.0.1 (primary LAN's gateway), it says that WAN IP and gateway can't be in the same network. 
when I change the IP to 192.168.1.105 it says that both WAN IP and gateway IP should be in the same network. I have then put 192.168.1.105 as IP and 192.168.0.1 as gateway. It worked but the internet didn't.
What to do now?

Are you sure the cable is physically okay? If you have DHCP available but it no longer works, that doesn't mean that you should switch to using a static IP address – rather, it means you should investigate why DHCP no longer works, because that's probably the same reason Internet access no longer works as well (i.e. packets aren't getting through in general).

Good advice. I think the cable is okay as in the secondary router the WAN port is giving green signal. But I will double check and let you know.

Do you have any other device that you could test on the same cable (e.g. a laptop) in place of the Tenda N300? Does that get a DHCP address when connected and does it have Internet access?

Also can you post a screenshot of the entire page where the "WAN IP and gateway can't be in the same network" error message comes from? That's a weird message, and the only way it makes sense is if the N300 uses some mixed-up terminology... or I guess if it refers to its own LAN IP address as 'gateway' in the message, which indeed can't overlap with the WAN address.

theres nothing wrong to have it set on static ip, in fact it is always preferable due to easier management. assuming tplink is your main router the topology should be as: INTERNET > WAN_TPLINK > TPLINK_LAN > WAN_TENDA where tplink=192.168.0.1 and tenda=192.168.1.1 (or 105 if you rly wish)

I actually checked the cable with my laptop and PC, getting "Ethernet doesn't have a valid IP configuration". I think the problem is in the cable.

What is it your actually trying to do with this configuration?  What are the device's attached to these routers and configuration intentions?  It feels like there's an easier way...

I have a router in both ends of my house. As the primary router doesn't cover the whole house

Thanks for the suggestion guys. It was cable problem. My ISP guy fixed it.
